# fOpen + fWrite -a , Data from file erased after while.

Tags: php, heroku, append, fopen, fwrite

i have a script that writes customer data to a file, after a few entries, the customers.txt file goes blank while it is being hosted on heroku servers. What can be the source of this problem? Needless to say im no programming guru and all help is very welcome, thank you.

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$data = "$fname | $lname | $dob | $email | $phone"."\r\n ";

$fh = fopen("customers.txt", "a");

fwrite($fh, $data);


fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Is this the only script running, and the only time you're opening customers.txt? (Most likely, another program is already consuming the file) Also, does the problem occur on a brand-new heroku instance? Can you reproduce it on your local installation?

Comment: Yes this is the only script running. It is a very simple setup. Yes it is a brand new instance of heroku. The  process is set up the following way

HTML Form action="submit.php" with the  above script - > submit.php with the php in the top followed by a html "thank you" page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the data somewhere else besides the filesystem on Heroku.  The cedar stack has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) so you cannot expect data you write there to remain there.